# [greek]babel + cleveref + Roman pagenumbering + label = ☇

Tags: page-numbering, labels, babel, cleveref, babel-greek

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}%%% greek should not necessarily be the main language; e.g., [greek, ngerman] would also expose the bug.
\usepackage{cleveref}%%% option [ngerman] would not change the outcome.
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\label{someLabel}
\end{document}
```

as `mwe.tex` to `pdflatex` leads to

> ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 6.  \fi <*> mwe
>
> ?

Versions:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
- LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
- cleveref 0.21.4 or 0.21.5 (both expose the bug)
- greek.ldf 2020/11/10 v1.10
- babel 2021/07/22 3.63

The bug occurs in current Debian testing "bookworm": https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=997024

The maintainers of `cleveref`, `greek.ldf`, and `babel` have been informed. Meanwhile, any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can restore the original Roman counter formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\@RomanSaved\@Roman
\usepackage[greek]{babel}%%% greek should not necessarily be the main language; e.g., [greek, ngerman] would also expose the bug.
\usepackage{cleveref}%%% option [ngerman] would not change the outcome.
\let\@Roman\@RomanSaved
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\setcounter{page}{5}

\label{someLabel}
{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\pageref{someLabel}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But `\pageref{someLabel}` might produce really weird output. Try with `\setcounter{page}{5}` and issue `\pageref{someLabel}`.

Comment: @egreg well it typesets as V so  in either case you need `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont` or a babel equivalent to see it typeset using a latin font.

Comment: No, it typesets an accent.

Comment: @egreg ? it looks like a V to me, example extended.

Comment: Of course that works, but… My solution works without special treatments.

Comment: @egreg sure but as I say I restore the original \Roman.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To see the right outcome in English, we should say something like `\usepackage[greek,USenglish]{babel}`. Otherwise we get garbage instead of the bottom number: https://i.imgur.com/iS41D0P.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `\ensureascii` macro. You can make it `\protected`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\AtBeginDocument{\robustify\ensureascii}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\label{someLabel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, `\ensureascii` is (indirectly) protected. The real issue in an `\edef` applied to `\thepage` instead of a `\protected@edef` in `cleveref`. But it’s a nice workaround.

Comment: @JavierBezos `cleveref` expects `\@Roman` to be fully expandable (which it should be). Of course we all know the quirks of LGR encoding… In any case, littering the `.aux` file with `{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont...}` is not the best.

Comment: Not exactly – `cleveref` expects `\thepage` to be fully expandable, and that’s wrong (the buggy line is `\edef\@tempb{\thepage}`) . `\the...`  representations are not required to be fully expandable, and you can find examples in the LaTeX Companion where clearly they are not. Using `\edef` instead of `\protected@edef` with arbitrary stuff is a ‘classic’ (I myself have made this mistake several times). In fact, it fails even if you define `\ensureascii` with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, because the `\protect` is ignored, the reason being, again, the `\edef`. @egreg

Comment: Here is a MWE bombing without `babel`: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{cleveref} \renewcommand\thepage{\textit{\arabic{page}}} \begin{document} \label{someLabel} Text \end{document}`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Yes, that bombs, but the definition is very dubiously useful.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks! The maintainer of cleveref has not responded yet. So, would a (proper but temporary) patch be replacing `\edef\@tempb{\thepage}` with `\protected@edef\@tempb{\thepage}` in a local copy of `cleveref.sty`, or is there more to be done?

Comment: @egreg You document produces no output. Saying `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\AtBeginDocument{\robustify\ensureascii}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\label{someLabel}Test
\cref{someLabel}
\end{document}` produces question marks instead of the reference.

Comment: @GeekestGeek That label refers to nothing (it can only be used for `\pageref`. Add `\section{test}` in front of it and retry.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, you're right! I don't know what I was thinking.